# Liquibase db migration not happen when I put the task in gradle file

Tags: java, gradle, groovy, liquibase

I add a gradle task for liquibase db migration as below

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.liquibase:liquibase-core:4.4.3'
        classpath "org.liquibase:liquibase-gradle-plugin:2.0.4"
        classpath 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.13'
    }
}


plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.liquibase.gradle' version '2.0.4'
}

task dbmigrate {
    doLast {
        println "executing dev"
       
            liquibase {
                activities {
                    schema1 {
                        changeLogFile "$projectDir/src/main/resources/db/migrations.xml"
                        url 'jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bmw?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&characterEncoding=UTF-8&serverTimezone=UTC'
                        username 'root'
                        password 'root'
                        driver 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'
                    }
                    schema2 {
                        changeLogFile '$projectDir/src/main/resources/db/migrations.xml'
                        url 'jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/vw?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&characterEncoding=UTF-8&serverTimezone=UTC'
                        username 'root'
                        password 'root'
                        driver 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'
                    }
                }
                runList = 'schema1, schema2'
            }
        }
    }

build.dependsOn dbmigrate
```

When I ran `gradlew build` or `gradlew task dbmigrate`, it printed out as successful with the words "executing dev". However, when I check the dbs, none of the table schema changes are applied.

Any ideas? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there's a few things missing in your `build.gradle`. I tried executing the command `./gradlew task dbmigrate update`, so with the extra `update` command. This gave me a few errors, such as that Liquibase was missing as a runtime dependency.

I added this to your build file, and then it worked for me when I ran `./gradlew task dbmigrate update`:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
        liquibaseRuntime("org.liquibase:liquibase-core:4.4.3")
        liquibaseRuntime("mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.13")
}
```